# Wrong e-mail address in "git log"

Tags: github

I commited several files to my repo without having a .gitconfig file with username and e-mail details, so git took the wrong e-mail I specified in my linux /etc/hostname file.

This is the repo I'm talking about, the grayed-out commits with name "Leslie King" don't link to anything:
https://github.com/zoliky/dotfiles/commits/master

Is there anything wrong in leaving as is? I don't really want to mess with modifying the git log. I will continue commiting with the good e-mail from now on. I'm just wondering if there's anything wrong in leaving the old commits as is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, under normal circumstances this will not be a problem.

The only place it may be an issue would be if you were making submissions to a larger Open Source project that requires all submitters to sign a contributors agreement, the automated systems that manage these would see this code as being contributed by 2 separate people (1 per email address).

If you really want to "fix" it then you could look at this set of instructions https://help.github.com/articles/changing-author-info/